# add specific string to a specific line at the end. -bash

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have a textfile(particulars.txt) which contains

personId,personName,employmentType

particulars.txt

```
1,jane,partTime
2,bob,fullTime
3,john,fullTime
```

How to do I make it such that if I key in the name of the worker, it will check whether that person is full time or part time worker and prompts the user to key in the salary and rewrite back to the file just for that person. I will explain in more details.

for example

```
Enter Name:jane 
jane is a partTime staff
Enter Hourly Salary:10
```

so the textfile(particulars.txt) will now be

```
1,jane,partTime,10
2,bob,fullTime
3,johnfullTime
```

example two

```
Enter Name:bob
bob is a fullTime staff
Enter monthly Salary:1600
```

so the textfile(particulars.txt) will now be

```
1,jane,partTime,10
2,bob,fullTime,1600
3,john,fullTime
```

this is what I have 
my code

```
#!/bin/bash
fileName="particulars.txt"
read -p "Enter name:" name
if grep -q $name $fileName; then
     employmentType=$(grep $name $fileName | cut -d, -f4)
     echo "$name is $employmentType" staff"
     if [ $employmentType == "partTime" ]; then
          echo "Enter hourly pay:" 
          read hourlyPay
          #calculations for monthly salary(which I have not done)

     elif [ $employmentType == "fullTime" ]; then
          echo "Enter monthly salary:" 
          read monthlySalary         
     fi    
else 
    echo "No record found"
fi

read -p "Press[Enter Key] to Contiune.." readEnterKey
```

I am only able to find which employment type does the person belongs to, but I am not sure of how/what should I do to add the salary at the end of the line just for that particular person. i have read up on sed , but I'm still confused on how to use sed to achieve my results and thus seeking help from you guys. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just modified your script.

```
#!/bin/bash
fileName="particulars.txt"
read -p "Enter name:" name
if grep -q $name $fileName; then
     employmentType=$(grep $name $fileName | cut -d, -f3)
     emp_name=$(grep $name $fileName | cut -d, -f2)  # Getting emp name
     emp_id=$(grep $name $fileName | cut -d, -f1)    # Getting id
     echo "$name is $employmentType staff"
     if [ $employmentType == "partTime" ]; then
          echo "Enter hourly pay:" 
          read hourlyPay
          #calculations for monthly salary(which I have not done)
          sed -i "s/^$emp_id.*$/&,$hourlyPay/g" $fileName  # Modifying the file by using id.

     elif [ $employmentType == "fullTime" ]; then
          echo "Enter monthly salary:" 
          read monthlySalary
     fi
else
    echo "No record found"
fi

read -p "Press[Enter Key] to Contiune.." readEnterKey
```

I have added the below lines.

```
emp_id=$(grep $name $fileName | cut -d, -f1)
emp_name=$(grep $name $fileName | cut -d, -f2)
sed -i "s/^$emp_id.*$/&,$hourlyPay/g" $fileName
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless you *need* to do it in an interactive manner, you can say:

```
sed '/\bbob\b/{s/$/,1600/}' filename
```

This would add `,1600` to the line matching `bob`.  Note that by specifying word boundaries `\b`, you'd ensure that the change is done only for `bob`, not `abob` or `boba`.

You can use the `-i` option to make the changes to the file *in-place*:

```
sed -i '/\bbob\b/{s/$/,1600/}' filename
```

---

EDIT: In order to use shell variable, use double quotes for the `sed` command:

```
 sed "/\b$employeeName\b/{s/^$/,$monthlySalary/}" filename
```

Comment: thanks for your advice. is it possible if I could change it to something like                                                     **sed '/\$employeeName{s/$,$monthlySalary}' filename**? in this way I will be doing it in a more interactive way rather than just changing for bob only

Comment: @user2211678 Yes, you were close except that you need to use double quotes.  See edit above.